# Tensorflow csv input pipline: Shuffle batches but preserve sequence order within each batch

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I build a recurrent neural network in tensorflow. Then I build a pipeline to import training data from my dataset (within a csv file) into my model. The procedure in the code section (source: [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data)) works perfectly.

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["file0.csv", "file1.csv"])

reader = tf.TextLineReader()
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

# Default values, in case of empty columns. Also specifies the type of the
# decoded result.
record_defaults = [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 = tf.decode_csv(
    value, record_defaults=record_defaults)
features = tf.stack([col1, col2, col3, col4])

with tf.Session() as sess:
  # Start populating the filename queue.
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

  for i in range(1200):
    # Retrieve a single instance:
    example, label = sess.run([features, col5])

  coord.request_stop()
  coord.join(threads)
```

The only additional thing is, that I use

```
data_batch = tf.train.batch(
                [features], batch_size=n_steps_mul_batch_size, capacity=capacity)
data_batch_reshaped = tf.reshape(
            data_batch, [batch_size, n_steps, feature_num])
```

to create batches for training in the shape [batch_size x timesteps x features].

**Now my question:**

I want to pass randomized/shuffled training data to my model, but at the same time preserve the sequence ordering within each batch. So the batches as a whole should be randomized/shuffled, but the sequences within each batch should preserve the original sequence order. Is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there no simple way to do it in Tensorflow.

But, you can do it manually:

```
import numpy as np
import random

def get_next_batch(data, batch_size):
    size = data.shape[0]
    rand_samples = random.sample(data[:, 0, 0], batch_size)
    data_batch = np.array([data[i] for i in range(size) if data[i, 0, 0] in rand_samples])
    return data_batch
```